# Converting Numbers to Words in php

Tags: php

```
<?php
define("MAJOR", 'pounds');
define("MINOR", 'p');
class toWords
{
    var $pounds;
    var $pence;
    var $major;
    var $minor;
    var $words = '';
    var $number;
    var $magind;
    var $units = array('', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine');
    var $teens = array('ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen');
    var $tens = array('', 'ten', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety');
    var $mag = array('', 'thousand', 'million', 'billion', 'trillion');

    function toWords($amount, $major = MAJOR, $minor = MINOR)
    {
        $this->major  = $major;
        $this->minor  = $minor;
        $this->number = number_format($amount, 2);
        list($this->pounds, $this->pence) = explode('.', $this->number);
        $this->words = " $this->major $this->pence$this->minor";
        if ($this->pounds == 0)
            $this->words = "Zero $this->words";
        else {
            $groups = explode(',', $this->pounds);
            $groups = array_reverse($groups);
            for ($this->magind = 0; $this->magind < count($groups); $this->magind++) {
                if (($this->magind == 1) && (strpos($this->words, 'hundred') === false) && ($groups[0] != '000'))
                    $this->words = ' and ' . $this->words;
                $this->words = $this->_build($groups[$this->magind]) . $this->words;
            }
        }
    }

    function _build($n)
    {
        $res = '';
        $na  = str_pad("$n", 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        if ($na == '000')
            return '';
        if ($na{0} != 0)
            $res = ' ' . $this->units[$na{0}] . ' hundred';
        if (($na{1} == '0') && ($na{2} == '0'))
            return $res . ' ' . $this->mag[$this->magind];
        $res .= $res == '' ? '' : ' and';
        $t = (int) $na{1};
        $u = (int) $na{2};
        switch ($t) {
            case 0:
                $res .= ' ' . $this->units[$u];
                break;
            case 1:
                $res .= ' ' . $this->teens[$u];
                break;
            default:
                $res .= ' ' . $this->tens[$t] . ' ' . $this->units[$u];
                break;
        }
        $res .= ' ' . $this->mag[$this->magind];
        return $res;
    }
}
```

Used:

```
$amount = 12345.67;
$obj    = new toWords($amount);
echo $obj->words; // gives Twelve thousand three hundred forty five pounds 67p
echo '<br/>';
echo $obj->number; // gives 12,345.67
```

Please the code above converts numbers to words but the problem I am faced with is how to change the last two digits after the dot (thus changing .67 to sixty seven)  into words.Please I will appreciate if you could help me.Thanks

Comment: You might be re-inventing the wheel on this one.  Its been done before:  http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/convert-numbers-to-words-with-php/

Comment: Thanks by the way, but this look different.Can we amend to suit the code above.

Comment: Please I can't seem to fix this,can you help please

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Please I am not seeking for codes, I needed ideas on how to figure my problem and how to solve them.Thanks for your Cooperation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Naively, without dissecting your code too much, you could just call your existing code on the numbers to the left of the decimal, and then on the numbers to the right of the decimal, and then stick them together.  It's a bit of a hack but it works:

```
<?php
define("MAJOR", 'pounds');
define("MINOR", 'p');
class toWords
{
    var $pounds;
    var $pence;
    var $major;
    var $minor;
    var $words = '';
    var $number;
    var $magind;
    var $units = array('', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine');
    var $teens = array('ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen');
    var $tens = array('', 'ten', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety');
    var $mag = array('', 'thousand', 'million', 'billion', 'trillion');

    function toWords($amount, $major = MAJOR, $minor = MINOR)
    {
        $this->__toWords__((int)($amount), $major);
        $whole_number_part = $this->words;
        #$right_of_decimal = (int)(($amount-(int)$amount) * 100);
        $strform = number_format($amount,2);
        $right_of_decimal = (int)substr($strform, strpos($strform,'.')+1);
        $this->__toWords__($right_of_decimal, $minor);
        $this->words = $whole_number_part . ' ' . $this->words;
    }

    function __toWords__($amount, $major)
    {
        $this->major  = $major;
        #$this->minor  = $minor;
        $this->number = number_format($amount, 2);
        list($this->pounds, $this->pence) = explode('.', $this->number);
        $this->words = " $this->major";
        if ($this->pounds == 0)
            $this->words = "Zero $this->words";
        else {
            $groups = explode(',', $this->pounds);
            $groups = array_reverse($groups);
            for ($this->magind = 0; $this->magind < count($groups); $this->magind++) {
                if (($this->magind == 1) && (strpos($this->words, 'hundred') === false) && ($groups[0] != '000'))
                    $this->words = ' and ' . $this->words;
                $this->words = $this->_build($groups[$this->magind]) . $this->words;
            }
        }
    }

    function _build($n)
    {
        $res = '';
        $na  = str_pad("$n", 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        if ($na == '000')
            return '';
        if ($na{0} != 0)
            $res = ' ' . $this->units[$na{0}] . ' hundred';
        if (($na{1} == '0') && ($na{2} == '0'))
            return $res . ' ' . $this->mag[$this->magind];
        $res .= $res == '' ? '' : ' and';
        $t = (int) $na{1};
        $u = (int) $na{2};
        switch ($t) {
            case 0:
                $res .= ' ' . $this->units[$u];
                break;
            case 1:
                $res .= ' ' . $this->teens[$u];
                break;
            default:
                $res .= ' ' . $this->tens[$t] . ' ' . $this->units[$u];
                break;
        }
        $res .= ' ' . $this->mag[$this->magind];
        return $res;
    }
}
?>
```

Now your test works:

```
$amount = 12345.67;
$obj    = new toWords($amount);
echo $obj->words; // gives twelve thousand three hundred and forty five  pounds  sixty seven  p
echo '<br/>';
echo $obj->number; // gives 12,345.67
```

Comment: Thanks genuis.It works but the last digits is converted wrongly, like when i enter 12.60, it converts it to twelve pounds fifty nine p instead of twelve pounds sixty p.

Comment: Yeah, that's because of the way it rounds the decimals.  I changed it so it should work better now -- changed the part that calculates the $right_of_decimal variable.

Comment: This explanation and answer saved me a week of headache. Thank you @murftown.

Comment: @murftown or somebody, would you explain shortly what do $na and  $res mean and do?