# convert spelled out numerals ( twenty two ) to digits ( 22 )

Tags: javascript, math, numbers, numeric

I'm trying to convert spelled out numeric strings into strings of digits / numbers.

I managed to do the opposite, below, but when I tried to reverse it, I didn't work so well ( it returned undefined undefined 00 undefined for 'two'.

```
var th = [ "", "thousand", "million", "billion", "trillion" ];

var dg = [ "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" ];

var tn = [ "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen" ];

var tw = [ "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety" ];

function toWords(s) {
    s = s.toString();
    s = s.replace(/[\, ]/g, "");
    if (s != parseFloat(s)) return "not a number";
    var x = s.indexOf(".");
    if (x == -1) x = s.length;
    if (x > 15) return "too big";
    var n = s.split("");
    var str = "";
    var sk = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        if ((x - i) % 3 == 2) {
            if (n[i] == "1") {
                str += tn[Number(n[i + 1])] + " ";
                i++;
                sk = 1;
             } else if (n[i] != 0) {
                str += tw[n[i] - 2] + " ";
                sk = 1;
             }
        } else if (n[i] != 0) {
            str += dg[n[i]] + " ";
            if ((x - i) % 3 == 0) str += "hundred ";
            sk = 1;
        }
        if ((x - i) % 3 == 1) {
            if (sk) str += th[(x - i - 1) / 3] + " ";
            sk = 0;
        }
    }
    if (x != s.length) {
        var y = s.length;
        str += "point ";
        for (var i = x + 1; i < y; i++) str += dg[n[i]] + " ";
    }
    return str.replace(/\s+/g, " ");
}
```

Can someone help me reverse this in javascript ( original in javascript as well )? Or give me some advice on how I can accomplish what I am trying to do.

I've tried using a parser, but I feel like then I am defining one = 1, two = 2,... sixteen = 16, seventeen = 17,... and seventy-three = 73. So essentially literally defining many of the numeric strings with their number counterparts. There has to be a better way to do this.

ML has crossed my mind, but why have something learn? one is 1. I'm not getting various inputs and trying to relate it / match it to a single output. For example hello, hey, hi, and anything like it is a greeting.

Comment: 'Undefined' means you didn't add your code to the question. :)

Comment: In spoken numbers, the word "hundred" is typically followed by "and", as in "one hundred and six", but not when the number is an even hundred, e.g. "seven hundred".

Comment: @RobG The logic I figured was is a spelled out number is before a spelled out number then multiply them ( seven hundred becomes 7*100 = 700. ) If it is after then add them ( one hundred five becomes 100+5 ) so the and isn't even needed.

Comment: tried google? http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/convert-numbers-to-words-with-php/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633985/converting-numbers-to-words-in-php

Comment: @user3743069—907 becomes "nine hundred seven", but is generally spoken as "nine hundred and seven".

Comment: @Prashank No need to be rude. Yes, I did try Google. That is numbers to words. My script does that. I need to do the reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, english numbering is resonably consistent, apart from the tens. You would need to define the strings for 'one' to 'nineteen', all the tens from 'twenty' to 'ninety', 'hundred', 'thousand', 'million', etc.

Then, for the parser, parse the string to tokens (basically split it). If you like, you can convert the tokens to numbers, or you can leave them as strings if you like. I use numbers here, because it's a bit shorter. :)

So, if you have a string of "four thousand hundred and eighty five", you could parse this to the tokens:

> 4 1000 100 80 5

(you can discard the word 'and', as well as commas and other noise.)

Then, you can process this string from the back in the following very simplified pseudo code.

Total = 0;
Multiplicator = 1;

```
repeat
  Number = ReadNumber || 1;
  Total += Multiplicator * Number;
  Multiplicator = ReadMultiplicator;
```

The multiplicator are 10, 20, 30 .. 100, 1000, 1000000
The numbers are 1 .. 19. These are optional. If there is no number found, treat it as if one was read.

So in the end, you should treat the string as

> 4 1000 1 100 1 80 5

Which should be processed as

> 5 + 1 * 80 +  1 * 100 + 4 * 1000

I said the pseudo code is very simplified. First of all, your parsed needs to be able to 'peek' ahead. If the preceding token isn't a number, it must be a multiplicator, so it should not be skipped.
Furthermore, you want some extra checks. After all, numbers until 100 are special. You wouldn't want to parse the string "three eighty four" to 244.

And then you need some extra layer. What about "eighty five thousand"? It looks like you shouldn't read just one number before a multiplicator, but actually all tokens that are smaller than the multiplicator, and parse them together, so

> one hundred sixty thousand

Should be parsed as

> (1 100 1 60) 1000

You might add extra checks in that piece later, although you can do without at first. After all, "thousand million" is actually a "billion", but it will parse correctly and even give the right outcome.

So, I think parsing correct strings is quite doable. Checking for exceptions makes it a bit harder. "twenty three hundred" will work out of the box, but it's weird that you could also write "ten thousand twenty three hundred" and actually get an outcome of 12.300. But then again, checks like that are not strictly needed at first, I guess.

Comment: one question. when reading the numbers, I see in your logic that you use `1` when a number isn't read in, but a 1 is read in before 100 and before 80. why? why isn't it 1 4 1 1000 1 100 1 80 1 5 or actually 4 1000 100 80 5? Numbers are being read every time so why would there be ones? I see how multiplying by ones cause the parsed number to be correct, but where and why did the come from?

Comment: You need to do that only for the numbers before the multiplicators, but come to think of that, maybe that step isn't really necessary at all. After all, you don't write 'hundred', you write 'one hundred', unlike in some other languages.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want integers,  you can use an object of key values to build the numbers from individual words-

```
function wordsToNumber(s){
    var w= s.toLowerCase().replace(/(thousand|[mbr]illion),?/g, '$1,');
    var n= 0, nArray= w.split(/,/), 
    sub= 0, tem, segment, 
    nwords={
        billion: 1e9, eight: 8, eighteen: 18, eighty: 80, 
        eleven: 11, fifteen: 15, fifty: 50,  five: 5, forty: 40, 
        four: 4, fourteen: 14,  hundred: 100, million: 1e6,  
        nine: 9, nineteen: 19, ninety: 90, one: 1, quadrillion: 1e15, 
        seven: 7, seventeen: 17, seventy: 70, six: 6, sixteen: 16, 
        sixty: 60, ten: 10,  thirteen: 13, thirty: 30, thousand: 1e3, 
        three: 3, trillion: 1e12,twelve: 12, twenty: 20, two: 2, zero: 0
    };
    while(nArray.length){
        sub= 0;
        segment= nArray.shift().match(/[a-z]+/g) || [];
        segment.forEach(function(w2){
            tem= nwords[w2.trim()];
            if(isFinite(tem)){
                if(tem<100) sub+= tem;
                else sub*= tem;
            }
        });
        n+= sub;
    }
    return n;
}
var str= 'twenty two thousand one hundred and fifty one';

wordsToNumber(str);

/*  returned value: (Number)
22151
*/
```

For more capability, you can write more code-

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset= "utf-8">
<title>Number Words</title>
<style>
</style>
<script>
Math.fraction= function(n, prec, up){
    var s= String(n), 
    p= s.indexOf('.');
    if(p== -1) return s;
    var i= Math.floor(n) || '', 
    dec= s.substring(p), 
    m= prec || Math.pow(10, dec.length-1), 
    num= up=== 1? Math.ceil(dec*m): Math.round(dec*m), 
    den= m, 
    g= Math.gcd(num, den);
    if(den/g== 1) return String(i+num);
    if(i) i= i+' and  ';
    return i+ String(num/g)+'/'+String(den/g);
}
Number.fromFraction= function(str, prec){
    var rx=/(\d+)\/(\d+)/, dec= 0, I= 0, 
    M= rx.exec(str);
    if(M){
        if(M.index>0) I= parseFloat(str);
        if(M[1]) dec= M[1]/M[2];
        if(!prec) prec= str.length+1;
        if(typeof prec== 'number') dec= +(dec.toFixed(prec));
        return I+dec;
    }
    return parseFloat(str);
}
Number.fromRoman= function(s){
    s= String(s).toUpperCase();
    if(s.length>15 ||  /[^MDCLXVI]/.test(s)) return NaN;
    var L= s.length, sum= 0, i= 0, next, val, 
    R={
        M: 1000, D: 500, C: 100, L: 50, X: 10, V: 5, I: 1
    };
    while(i<L){
        val= s.charAt(i++);
        if(!R[val]) return NaN;
        val= R[val];
        next= R[(s.charAt(i) || 'N')] || 0;
        if(next>val) val*= -1;
        sum+= val;
    }
    if(sum.toRoman()== s) return sum;
    return NaN;
}
Number.prototype.toRoman= function(){
    var n= Math.floor(this), val, s= '', limit= 3999, i= 0, 
    v= [1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1], 
    r= ['M', 'CM', 'D', 'CD', 'C', 'XC', 'L', 'XL', 'X', 'IX', 'V', 'IV', 'I'];
    if(n<1 || n>limit) return '';
    while(i<13){
        val= v[i];
        while(n>= val){
            n-= val;
            s+= r[i];
        }
        if(n== 0) return s;
        ++i;
    }
    return '';
}
var NW={
    /* numbers to words */
    nameNumbers: function(str){
        var nw= NW.numberWords, 
        s= (str+'').replace(/([^\d])(?=\.\d+)/g, '$1 0').trim();
        var f, w= '', x, xs, n, ns, M, 
        rx=/(-?\d+)(\.(\d+)([eE]([+-]?\d+))?)?/g, 
        rx2=/(\d+)(\.(\d+)([eE]([+-]?\d+))?)?/, 
        rq=/((\d+)? +(and +)?)?(\d+)\/(\d+)/g;
        s= s.replace(rq, function(a){
            return NW.printFraction(a);
        });
        s= s.replace(rx, function(q){
            n= +q;
            ns= n+'';
            M= rx2.exec(ns) || [];
            w= (n<0)? 'minus ': '';
            if(M[1]) w+= nw(M[1]);
            if(M[3]){
                f= M[3].split('').map(function(itm){
                    return nw(itm);
                });
                w+= ' point '+ f.join(' ');
                if(M[5]){
                    x= +M[5];
                    xs= x<0? 'minus ': '';
                    xs+= NW.ordinal(nw(x));
                    w+= ' times ten to the '+xs;
                }
            }
            return w || q;
        });
        return s.replace(/ {2,}/g, ' ');
    },
    numberWords: function numberWords(x){
        var n= +x;
        if(isNaN(n) || n%1) return ''+x;
        n= Math.abs(n);
        var i= 0, p, prefix= [], num, rem, 
        NK= NW.numberwords_array, 
        w= NK[0], w1= NK[1], w2= NK[2], mag= NK[3];
        while(n>99){
            x= mag[i];
            if(n>= x){
                p= Math.floor(n/x);
                n%= x;
                prefix.push(numberWords(p)+w2[i]);
            }
            ++i;
        }
        if(prefix.length){
            prefix= prefix.join(', ');
            if(n) prefix+= ' and ';
            else return prefix;
        }
        else prefix= '';
        if(n<20) num= w[n];
        else{
            num= w1[Math.floor(n/10)];
            rem= n%10;
            if(rem) num+= ' '+w[rem];
        }
        return prefix+num;
    },
    numberwords_array: [
        ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 
        'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 
        'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen'], 
        ['', '', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 
        'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'], 
        [' quadrillion', ' trillion', ' billion', ' million', 
        ' thousand', ' hundred'], 
        [1e15, 1e12, 1e9, 1e6, 1e3, 100]
    ], 
    ordinal: function(s){
        var ax, rx, suffix, str= ' '+s.trim();
        ax= str.lastIndexOf(' ');
        suffix= str.substring(ax).toLowerCase();
        if(str.charAt(str.length-1)== 'y'){
            return str.slice(0, -2)+'tieth';
        }
        if(ax>1) str= str.substring(0, ax);
        else str= ' ';
        switch(suffix.trim()){
            case 'one': return str+' first';
            case 'two': return str+' second';
            case 'three': return str+' third';
            case 'five': return str+' fifth';
            case 'eight': return str+' eighth';
            case 'nine': return str+' ninth';
            case 'twelve': return str+' twelfth';
            default: return str+suffix+'th';
        }
    },
    printFraction: function(str){
        var num, RN= NW.numberWords, 
        M=/((\d+) +)?(\d+) *\/ *(\d+)/g.exec(str.trim());
        if(!M) return str;
        num= M[2]? RN(M[2])+' and ': '';
        num+= RN(+M[3])+'-';
        if(M[4]=== '2') num+= 'half';
        else if(M[4]=== '4') num+= 'quarter';
        else num+= NW.ordinal(RN(+M[4]));
        if(M[3]!== '1') num+= 's';
        return num;
    },
    /* words to numbers */
    reDigit: function(n){
        var sub= [], tem, d= n.match(/[a-z]+/g), L= d.length-1, 
        nwords= NW.wordnumber_keys;
        d.map(function(w, i){
            tem= nwords[w];
            if(isFinite(tem)){
                if(tem<20 || i== L) sub.push(tem+'');
                else sub.push((tem+'').charAt(0));
            }
        });
        return sub.join('');
    },
    reFraction: function(str){
        var M, w= 0, n, d, f2= 0, prec, ax;
        ax= str.lastIndexOf(' and ');
        if(ax== -1){
            ax= 0;
            w= 'zero';
        }
        else{
            w= str.substring(0, ax);
            ax+= 4;
        }
        M= str.substring(ax).split('-');
        n= M[0];
        d= M[1];
        if(n && d){
            d= NW.wordsToNumber(d);
            n= NW.wordsToNumber(n);
            return [w, n/d];
        }
        return [w];
    },
    wordNumber: function(str){
        var n= 0, sign= 1, whole= 0, dec= 0, frac, 
        suffix= 0, exp= 1, exsign= 1, prec, pt, 
        rx1=  /(illion|thousand|hundred)/i, 
        rx2=/( +times ten to the( +minus)? +)/g, 
        rx3=/(point|times|[^a-z, ])/, 
        s= str.toLowerCase().trim().replace(/ieth?$/, 'y').replace(/(ths?|s)$/, '');
        if(s.indexOf('minus ')== 0){
            sign= -1;
            s= s.substring(5);
        }
        if(!rx3.test(s)){
            n= (!rx1.test(s))? NW.reDigit(s): NW.wordsToNumber(s);
            return n*sign;
        }
        whole= s;
        var pt= s.split('point ');
        dec= pt[1];
        if(dec){
            whole= pt[0];
            temp= rx2.exec(dec);
            if(temp!= null){
                if(temp[2]) exsign= -1;
                suffix= dec.substring(rx2.lastIndex);
                dec= dec.substring(0, temp.index);
                suffix= NW.wordsToNumber(suffix);
                exp= Math.pow(10, suffix*exsign);
            }
            dec= NW.reDigit(dec);
            prec= dec.length+1;
            dec= +('0.'+dec);
        }
        else if(whole.indexOf('-')!= -1){
            pt= NW.reFraction(whole);
            whole= pt[0];
            dec= pt[1];
        }
        n= NW.wordsToNumber(whole.replace(/ +and +/g, ' '));
        if(dec){
            n+= dec;
            if(!prec) frac= Math.min(String(n).length, 15);
            n= n.toPrecision(frac);
        }
        if(exp!== 1) return sign*((n*exp).toExponential(prec));
        return sign*n;
    },
    wordnumber_keys:{
        billion: 1e9, eigh: 8, eight: 8, eighteen: 18, eightt: 8, eighty: 80, 
        eleven: 11, fif: 5, fifteen: 15, fifty: 50, first: 1, five: 5, forty: 40, 
        four: 4, fourteen: 14, half: 2, hundred: 100, million: 1e6, nin: 9, 
        nine: 9, nineteen: 19, ninety: 90, one: 1, quadrillion: 1e15, quarter: 4, 
        second: 2, seven: 7, seventeen: 17, seventy: 70, six: 6, sixteen: 16, 
        sixty: 60, ten: 10, third: 3, thirteen: 13, thirty: 30, thousand: 1e3, 
        three: 3, trillion: 1e12, twelf: 12, twelve: 12, twenty: 20, two: 2, zero: 0
    },
    wordsToNumber: function(s){
        var w= s.toLowerCase().replace(/(thousand|[mbr]illion),?/g, '$1,');
        var n= 0, nArray= w.split(/,/), 
        sub= 0, tem, segment, 
        nwords= NW.wordnumber_keys;
        while(nArray.length){
            sub= 0;
            segment= nArray.shift().match(/[a-z]+/g) || [];
            segment.forEach(function(w2){
                tem= nwords[w2.trim()];
                if(isFinite(tem)){
                    if(tem<100) sub+= tem;
                    else sub*= tem;
                }
            });
            n+= sub;
        }
        return n;
    }
}

onload=function(){
    var nw= NW, v2= [], v;
    var A= ['150', '0.12', 'fourteen hundred and ninety two', '65 1/16', '65.0045', 
    'thirty three and one- third', '2012', '98.6', 'MCMLIX', '897456971.25', 
    '1 1/2', '12 3/4', '-9', '33 1/3', Math.PI, 'nine and three- quarters', 
    'seventy eight point six four', 'XIX', '1.1550046210e+17', '1.222e3', 'minus two hundred', 
    '4.5e-10', '3.125e-3', '1.56760e+25'].map(function(sv){
        if(/^[IVXLCDM]+$/.test(sv)) sv= Number.fromRoman(sv);
        if(/^[a-z ,-]+$/i.test(sv)){
            v2= nw.wordNumber(sv);
        }
        else v2= nw.nameNumbers(sv);
        return '<p\>'+sv+'= '+v2+'</p\>';
    });
    document.getElementById('resultset').innerHTML=A.join('\n');
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="resultset">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow. Doesn't handle "things like twenty three hundred", but apart from that it's great. I didn't think you could do it with so little code. Very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation of one of the other answers:

I like monkeypatching (yeah, yeah, I know...), but it can easily be removed from this implementation.

```js
var NUMBER_NAMES = {
  a: 1, billion: 1e9, eight: 8, eighteen: 18, eighty: 80,
  eleven: 11, fifteen: 15, fifty: 50,  five: 5, forty: 40,
  four: 4, fourteen: 14,  hundred: 100, million: 1e6,
  nine: 9, nineteen: 19, ninety: 90, one: 1, quadrillion: 1e15,
  seven: 7, seventeen: 17, seventy: 70, six: 6, sixteen: 16,
  sixty: 60, ten: 10,  thirteen: 13, thirty: 30, thousand: 1e3,
  three: 3, trillion: 1e12, twelve: 12, twenty: 20, two: 2, zero: 0
}

Array.prototype.last = function() {
  return this[this.length - 1];
}

String.prototype.toNumber = function() {
  var stripped = this.toLowerCase().replace(/\-| and /g, ' ').split(' ');
  var numbers = stripped.map(function(word) { return NUMBER_NAMES[word] });
  if (numbers.some(function(number) { return number == null })) return NaN;
  var parseNumbers = function(numbers) {
    var total = 0;
    var readNumber = function(def) {
      return (numbers.last() < 20) ? numbers.pop() : def;
    }
    var readMagnitude = function() {
      return (numbers.last() > 19) ? numbers.pop() : 0;
    }
    total += readNumber(0);
    while (numbers.length) {
      var magnitude = readMagnitude();
      var sub_numbers = [];
      while (numbers.length && numbers.last() < magnitude) {
        sub_numbers.unshift(numbers.pop());
      }
      var number = sub_numbers.length ? parseNumbers(sub_numbers) : 1;
      total += magnitude * number;
    }
    return total;
  }
  return parseNumbers(numbers);
}

"twenty-two hundred and one".toNumber() // 2201
```