# Convert number | integer to words

Tags: php, number-formatting

I would like to convert integer to words, for eg: 29 would become *TWENTY NINE* and 50 would be *FIFTY*. How can I achieve this using PHP?

Here is what I have so far but it isn't giving the desired output.

```
$fees_so = $form_data_fees['field']['4'];
$feesInWords = strval($fees_so);
echo $feesInWords;
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php - This function performs no formatting on the returned value. If you are looking for a way to format a numeric value as a string, please see sprintf() or number_format().

Comment: Did you debug `$form_data_fees['field']['4']` ? What does `$form_data_fees['field']` contain? Plase add a data example of that array to your question.

Comment: Please check this stackoverflow link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633985/converting-numbers-to-words-in-php  . It should solve your problem. Just tested it....

Comment: the $fees_so variable returns £29 which was selected from the php form.

Comment: @LalbhusanYadav There are better ways than that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [NumberFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) class with `SPELLOUT`:

```
$nf = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
echo $nf->format(1999); // one thousand nine hundred ninety-nine
```

Answer (score 2):

I eventually found a solution using the code from @aniket-sahrawat with a little tweaking

Here is the code in case anyone needs this in future...

```
<?php
$fees_so = $form_data_fees['field']['4'];
$words = filter_var($fees_so, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$nf = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
echo $nf->format($words);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an array:

```
$list_of_fees = array("£29", "£50", "£64");;
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
    echo substr($list_of_fees[$i], 1) . " Pounds";
```